# Would UDP over VPN eliminate packet loss?

Tags: networking, vpn, udp, site-to-site-vpn, video-streaming

I am receiving a MPTS UDP stream from a remote location and I am experiencing packet loss. I would like to know if there's any way to eliminate this packet loss while still using the UDP protocol?

I thought of using UDP over VPN. Is this even technically possible and, if so, will it eliminate packet loss in UDP?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, UDP over a VPN is possible, but no, that wouldn't change a thing. Although the underlying transport may be reliable, the UDP has been designed not to retransmit lost packets. If you really have a problem with packetloss, either switch to TCP for transport, fix it by making the application send UDP packets slower, or increase the bandwidth on the path (if the links are full).

Answer (score 3):

This fully depends why and where the packet loss is. Some examples:

- Your ISP "optimizes" the traffic and downgrades your UDP traffic. In this case a VPN would help unless the ISP downgrades also the VPN traffic.
- You don't have enough bandwidth to handle the traffic. In this case a VPN would not help.